# Using Case statement within update clause - Sybase

Tags: sql, sql-update, case

The following is sybase code. Can someone see if the following is correct. I guess I'm missing out on the syntax somewhere

```
    declare @test  varchar(32)
    select @test="/data/dump/team/"

    update link
    set link.value=
     case when @test=substring(link.value,1,17)
                   then @test
          when  @test != substring(link.value,1,17)
                      value
    end 
    where link.value != ""
    and link_id=0 and row_id = 462135
```

As it is give me the following error: "Incorrect syntax near keyword end on line 10."

Can please someone help me with the syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding "then" to the second case:

```
declare @test  varchar(32)
    select @test="/data/dump/team/"

    update link
    set link.value=
     case when @test=substring(link.value,1,17)
                   then @test
          when  @test != substring(link.value,1,17)
                   then value
    end
```

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was missing out....Why didn't my eye spot that hmmmmm!!! still wondering.. Thanks anyway..

Answer (score -1):

Why not simply do an "else" for the second "when" ?

Comment: Please comment on the respective answer as suggestion. Do not add as a separate answer